# Robot framework logs producing duplicate output when used with Unicon

Tags: robotframework

Hi I'm using robot framework with python specifically the unicon(https://pypi.org/project/unicon/) package. When using unicon without robot I do not get duplicate output in the stdout but when using unicon with robot in the logs I get duplicate output. I'm not quite sure what is causing this. The code is exactly the same. I'm not sending commands twice.

Expected each command to appear in the log once as evident in the stdout.
https://i.ibb.co/YBpnSg6/unicon-stdout-output.png

Results from log output:
https://i.ibb.co/K59PjQ2/duplicate-output-robot.png